# "hardens the heart like a stone"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to say

> Lack of compassion hardens your heart like a stone.

or

> Lack of compassion makes your heart as hard as stone.

I wouldn't mind some explanation of why these sentences are wrong or correct, or better.

Comment: I think one reason why it doesn't work perfectly is the cause-effect structure of the metaphor. Lack of compassion is the cause, hardened heart is the effect. But I think rather than cause-effect, these two things are better described as comparable, simultaneous qualities. *He lacked compassion, indeed, many said he had a heart of stone*

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't rule out a cause-effect structure...perhaps you first have lack of compassion without a fully stony heart, and then the final hardening occurs later. But I think this is a less natural way to view things.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I think cause-effect is what I am looking for. Yielding too often to one's tendency to lack compassion may lead with time to one's being unable of showing compassion even if he wanted to.

Comment: OK, then yes. If aiming for literary merit, be aware that *heart of stone* is quite a cliché idiom.

Answer (score 1):

> Lack of compassion hardens your heart like a stone.

This means that a lack of compassion hardens your heart like a stone hardens your heart!

Stones do not usually harden people's hearts, even metaphorically.

> Lack of compassion makes your heart as hard as stone.

This means that your heart becomes as hard as stone - a perfectly good simile.

---

Note: There may be better ways of expressing the metaphor, but I have merely explained why the sentences have different meanings.

Comment: Would you mind suggesting a better way of expressing this? The second one is what I meant

Comment: I am not a poet. I'll think about it!  P.S. The second sentence is perfectly correct.

Comment: Oh, but neither am I :)  Anyway, metaphors are not limited to poets, are they...

Comment: Maybe "A lack of compassion turns your heart to stone."